LaTeX3 fails to rescan strings containing a comment
If I store in a LaTeX3 string a string containing a comment and rescan it later, everything after the comment seems to be gone, like if the newline was not considered during the rescan. Am I doing something wrong here?
MWE
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{robust-externalize}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

% This puts the verbatim following code into a variable
% \l__robExt_placeholder___myplaceholder___str
\begin{PlaceholderFromCode}{__myplaceholder__}
  \scalebox{.6}{
    % If you remove this comment, the rest works as expected, otherwise you get an error "runaway argument"
    Hello
  }
\end{PlaceholderFromCode}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% Goal: store the content of the placeholder LaTeX3 string back into a macro
% (e.g. to search more efficiently the macros contained inside it etc)
\show\l__robExt_placeholder___myplaceholder___str
\tl_set_rescan:NnV \myMacro {} \l__robExt_placeholder___myplaceholder___str
\show \myMacro
\tl_analysis_show:N \myMacro
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}


You've saved in a str, so the newline is a character doesn't end the line with the comment char ... rescanning is famously tricky, I'd not use it unless you really must

@JosephWright So there is really no solution here?

Since you don't need the comments in the “externalized version”, you can set % to a comment character before grabbing the contents.

Since you grabbed with the \endlinechar being line feed, you just need to setup the rescan process with that character being the \newlinechar and \endlinechar:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{robust-externalize}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

% This puts the verbatim following code into a variable
% \l__robExt_placeholder___myplaceholder___str
\begin{PlaceholderFromCode}{__myplaceholder__}
  \scalebox{.6}{
    % If you remove this comment, the rest works as expected, otherwise you get an error "runaway argument"
    Hello
  }
\end{PlaceholderFromCode}


\ExplSyntaxOn
% Goal: store the content of the placeholder LaTeX3 string back into a macro
% (e.g. to search more efficiently the macros contained inside it etc)
\show\l__robExt_placeholder___myplaceholder___str
\tl_set_rescan:NnV \myMacro {\newlinechar=10 \endlinechar=10} \l__robExt_placeholder___myplaceholder___str
\show \myMacro
\tl_analysis_show:N \myMacro
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}

This prints the following to stdout:
> \l__robExt_placeholder___myplaceholder___str=macro:
->\scalebox{.6}{
  % If you remove this comment, the rest works as expected, otherwise you get a
n error "runaway argument"
  Hello
}
.
l.19 ...__robExt_placeholder___myplaceholder___str
                                                  
? 
> \myMacro=macro:
->\scalebox {.6}{
Hello
}
.
l.21 \show \myMacro
                   
? 
The token list \myMacro contains the tokens:
>  \scalebox (control sequence=\protected macro:#1->\@ifnextchar [{\Gsca\ETC.)
>  { (begin-group character {)
>  . (the character .)
>  6 (the character 6)
>  } (end-group character })
>  { (begin-group character {)
>  
 (the character 
)
>  H (the letter H)
>  e (the letter e)
>  l (the letter l)
>  l (the letter l)
>  o (the letter o)
>  
 (the character 
)
>  } (end-group character })
>  
 (the character 
).
<recently read> }
                 
l.22 \tl_analysis_show:N \myMacro
                                 
? 

If you also want the linefeeds to be turned into spaces (as it would be the case in normal TeX processing) you need to also change the category code of linefeed using \catcode10=5:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{robust-externalize}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

% This puts the verbatim following code into a variable
% \l__robExt_placeholder___myplaceholder___str
\begin{PlaceholderFromCode}{__myplaceholder__}
  \scalebox{.6}{
    % If you remove this comment, the rest works as expected, otherwise you get an error "runaway argument"
    Hello
  }
\end{PlaceholderFromCode}


\ExplSyntaxOn
% Goal: store the content of the placeholder LaTeX3 string back into a macro
% (e.g. to search more efficiently the macros contained inside it etc)
\show\l__robExt_placeholder___myplaceholder___str
\tl_set_rescan:NnV \myMacro {\newlinechar=10 \endlinechar=10 \catcode10=5} \l__robExt_placeholder___myplaceholder___str
\show \myMacro
\tl_analysis_show:N \myMacro
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}

which prints
> \l__robExt_placeholder___myplaceholder___str=macro:
->\scalebox{.6}{
  % If you remove this comment, the rest works as expected, otherwise you get a
n error "runaway argument"
  Hello
}
.
l.19 ...__robExt_placeholder___myplaceholder___str
                                                  
? 
> \myMacro=macro:
->\scalebox {.6}{ Hello } .
l.21 \show \myMacro
                   
? 
The token list \myMacro contains the tokens:
>  \scalebox (control sequence=\protected macro:#1->\@ifnextchar [{\Gsca\ETC.)
>  { (begin-group character {)
>  . (the character .)
>  6 (the character 6)
>  } (end-group character })
>  { (begin-group character {)
>    (blank space  )
>  H (the letter H)
>  e (the letter e)
>  l (the letter l)
>  l (the letter l)
>  o (the letter o)
>    (blank space  )
>  } (end-group character })
>    (blank space  ).
<recently read> }
                 
l.22 \tl_analysis_show:N \myMacro
                                 
? 


A bit of an explanation:
You can think of the (low level!) rescanning process that's available in e-TeX as an operation that writes its argument to a file and then reads back that file (but that process is completely expandable). The expl3 implementation uses that underlying mechanism and wraps it a bit to make it easier to handle (though this loses a bit of the flexibility, category codes get frozen during rescanning, so that if your contents would change category codes those wouldn't work).
But the essential bit is: This is like writing to a file, and reading that file back in.
In the following I use the term "linebreak" to describe a newline in a source file (however that might be encoded, as long as TeX understands it as an end of line).
Your environment tokenises the contents in a way that linebreaks get stored as linefeeds (character code 10, category 12). For that reason it's necessary to write the (imaginary) temporary file with the correct \newlinechar such that the temporary file has the linebreaks in the correct places. That's possible with simply using \newlinechar=10 .
However now the tricky part of rescanning kicks in: It uses whatever settings are active around it, and inside \ExplSyntaxOn (during your \tl_set_rescan:NnV) the current \endlinechar (the character TeX automatically inserts whenever it hits a linebreak) is 32 (a space), and that has category 9 (ignored). We need to set \endlinechar to a character that has category 5 (which is the line end category). The simplest solution would be to use \endlinechar=13 since that has category 5 usually. However, since we know for a fact that our temporary file can't contain a character with character code 10 (since we used that as \newlinechar), it's more robust to stick with that character, hence we use \endlinechar=10 to have TeX insert a linefeed, we just need to also set its category to 5 for it to behave like a normal linebreak in a normal input file.
The second argument to \tl_set_rescan:NnV is meant exactly for this kind of setup that should only be active while the contents are rescanned. Therefore you can use \tl_set_rescan:NnV \myMacro {\newlinechar=10 \endlinechar=10 \catcode10=5} \l__robExt_placeholder___myplaceholder___str (you might want to turn this into more expl3-like syntax instead of the plain TeX syntax I show here).
Please keep in mind that this is only a minimal change to get you started/running. There are still all the usual pitfalls to rescanning: all catcodes except those of linefeed (character 10) are whatever the context you're using this in has active; category codes are frozen inside the assigned token list (\myMacro in your case) afterwards.

Great thanks a lot, I was sure it had to do with some catcode trickeries, but couldn't tell what to do exactly ^^

@tobiasBora See my edit, if you want the line ends to be turned into spaces during rescanning you also need to set the category code accordingly.
